# Spring Boot forward request internally based on a parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm making calls to my API for different kind of custom events like:

```
const eventTypes = [
    'cards.addCard'
    'cards.updateCard',
    'lanes.addLane',
    'lanes.updateLane'
];

fetch(`http://localhost:8080/app/${roomId}/${eventType}`, {
    method: 'POST'
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
    ...
});
```

The `eventType` path variable should define which one of these controller methods will be called:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/cards")
public class CardController {

    @PostMapping("/{roomId}/createCard")
    public void createCard(@PathVariable Long roomId, @RequestBody MyEventData eventData) {
        ...
    }

    @PostMapping("/{roomId}/updateCard")
    public void updateCard(@PathVariable Long roomId, @RequestBody MyEventData eventData) {
        ...
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/lanes")
public class LaneController {

    @PostMapping("/{roomId}/addLane")
    public void addLane(@PathVariable Long roomId, @RequestBody MyEventData eventData) {
        ...
    }

    @PostMapping("/{roomId}/updateLane")
    public void updateLane(@PathVariable Long roomId, @RequestBody MyEventData eventData) {
        ...
    }

}
```

I prefer to use `eventType` from the path variable of the request but I can also put it inside the request body.

So how is it possible to forward a request in the same API to the right Controller's method by using its parameter (`eventType`)? For example:

`http://localhost:8080/app/2/cards.addCard` should call `CardController.createCard()`
`http://localhost:8080/app/2/lanes.updateLane` should call `LaneController.updateLane()`

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If your clients are going to issue a request to "/app/${roomId}/cards.addCard", why are you trying to create a rest controller that processes requests to "/cards/{roomid}/addCard" ?

Comment: @crig Actually very long story:) Basically, we are replacing the existing WebSocket system with rest calls with no modification on the front-end side.

Comment: Would it be simpler to have RestControllers that process either type of request and which call common handlers internally in the code that actually do the work? i.e. no logic exists in the RestControllers, they just pass the data to a common class or method.

Comment: @crig I was also thinking of like you said; giving the request data to a gateway service that will call other services based on the request event type. That can be my backup solution certainly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just switch the roomId with the eventType in the path attribute, like this :

```
@PostMapping("/createCard/{roomId}")

@PostMapping("/updateCard/{roomId}")
...
```

If you want to do a redirect, you can create a Filter that do a redirect based on the eventTyp, here is an example of doFilter implementation :

```
@Override
public void doFilter (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    String path = req.getRequestURI();


    if (path.equals("/a")) {
        req = new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
            @Override
            public String getRequestURI() {
                return "/b";
            }
        };
    }

    chain.doFilter (req, res);
}
```

Ref : [SpringBoot possible filter issue with redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308272/springboot-possible-filter-issue-with-redirection/52308340)

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it would work. The `eventType` is `cards.addCard` not `createCard`. I'm not allowed to modify the `eventType` namings.

Answer (score 1):

I know that not answering the original question, but still - in general client should not dictate the server implementation details. I would rework the url construction on client side instead of trying to adjust server to specific client's needs. e.g.

```
const eventTypes = [
    'cards.addCard'
    'cards.updateCard',
    'lanes.addLane',
    'lanes.updateLane'
];

const fetch = (eventType, roomId) => { // "cards.addCard", 1
  // ["cards", "addCard"]
  const [resource, action] = eventType.split('.');
  // http://localhost:8080/app/cards/1/addCard
  const url = `http://localhost:8080/app/${resource}/${roomId}/${action}`;
  // perform http request ...
}
```

In case you still need to do it on server, then this logic can be moved to some "Generic Controller" which going to handle them and forward further (pseudocode):

```
@Route("/")
class GenericController {

  @RequestMapping({"/{id}/{fullAction}")
  public String execute(
       @PathVariable String id, 
       @PathVariable String fullAction) {
    final var resource = fullAction.split(".")[0];
    final var action = fullAction.split(".")[1];
    return "forward:/" + resource + "/" + id + "/" + action;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice client solution anyway :)